# CPWQ displays document titles/notes instead of file names

Tags: sharepoint, cqwp

I'm new to the Sharepoint 2007 server. I've built the CQWP which sits on the homepage and displays files (Word/Excel docs) uploaded to the Shared Document library on any subsite. The issue I'm having is that CQWP displays document titles or notes instead of the actual file names. I would also like to display what subsite the document has been uploaded to.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks Roman

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will require some [customization of the CQWP's ItemStyle.xsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557.aspx). I would suggest taking a look at [Heather Solomon's site for a really good intro](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/customitemstyle.aspx).

I think the internal column names you will want to display are FileLeafRef or LinkFilename (just the document filename) and probably FileDirRef for the Subsite (although it also includes the Library name).

Some notes that I had from when I customized the CQWP:

- Always make a backup of ItemStyle.xsl
- An error in the ItemStyle.xsl file will break ALL content query web parts
- Watch out for newlines and spaces in between tags